# For two standard uniform RVs is there a way to find the $E[|U_1-U_2|]$ using the linearity rule, ie $E[X+Y] =E[X] + E[Y]$?

Tags: probability

The answer is $\frac{1}{3}$ and I know how to get it by either:

- finding $f_{|U_1-U_2|}(a) = 2 -2a$ and doing the expected value formula
- or by calculating $\int \int |x-y| dxdy$

It looks like $E[|U_1-U_2|] \neq E[|U_1|]-E[|U_2|]$ since the LHS is $\frac{1}{3}$ and the RHS is $0$.

**My questions**

1. What about the absolute value screws up the linearity of expected values?
2. Is there a way to solve this problem using linearity of expectations?

Comment: Also in the question the standard uniform RVs are independent. Thanks.

Comment: "If $U_1>U_2$ ... Then $E[|U_1-U_2|] = E[U_1-U_2] = E[U_1]-[U_2]=0$" Do you realize this statement is meaningless? Note that $E[|U_1-U_2|]$ is the unconditional expectation of $|U_1-U_2|$ hence what you mean by "If $U_1>U_2$" in this context is unclear?

Comment: @Did I agree the attempt I wrote in the comments isn't logical and it's poorly formatted. I was going to put a better attempt in the original post but I didn't want to make the post too long. Please disregard my attempt... can you help with the correct way of answering my 2 questions? Thanks for your patience.

Comment: You indicate yourself two correct ways to compute it. The attempt starting with replacing $E(|U-V|)$ by $E(|U|)-E(|V|)$ is of course absurd (and has nothing to do with linearity) since $|U-V|\ne|U|-|V|$ in general.

Comment: @Did Thanks, your comment definitely convinces me that you can't separate $E[|U-V|]$ into two components since it violates how absolute value works in general. Instead of doing a separation like in my bad attempt, is there a different way to solve this with linearity of expectation? For example... maybe conditioning. Or is it impossible? Thanks.

Comment: I posted an answer that uses linearity of expectation, but really the "right" way to find this expectation without any calculation at all, just from symmetry considersations, is to think of the interval as a cut circle; see e.g. [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2830236/6622).

Comment: @joriki Thanks for the link to the other question. I will study it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll write $\operatorname{abs}(x)$ for $|x|$ because mixed vertical bars for absolute values and conditional probabilities get rather confusing. We have

\begin{eqnarray*}
E[\operatorname{abs}(U_1-U_2)]
&=&
\frac12E[\operatorname{abs}(U_1-U_2)\mid U_1\gt U_2]
+
\frac12E[\operatorname{abs}(U_1-U_2)\mid U_1\le U_2]
\\
&=&
\frac12E[U_1-U_2\mid U_1\gt U_2]
+
\frac12E[U_2-U_1\mid U_1\le U_2]
\\
&=&
\frac12\left(E[U_1\mid U_1\gt U_2]-E[U_2\mid U_1\gt U_2]\right)
\\&&+
\frac12\left(E[U_2\mid U_1\le U_2]-E[U_1\mid U_1\le U_2]\right)
\;,
\\
&=&
E[U_1\mid U_1\gt U_2]-E[U_2\mid U_1\gt U_2]
\\
&=&
E[U_1\mid U_1\gt U_2]-(1-E[U_1\mid U_1\gt U_2])
\\
&=&
2E[U_1\mid U_1\gt U_2]-1\;,
\end{eqnarray*}

where the equalities are respectively due to the law of total probability, the definition of the absolute value, the linearity of expectation, symmetry considerations, again symmetry consideration, and finally simple algebra.

Now you just need a nice way to find $E[U_1\mid U_1\gt U_2]$ :-)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm working through Sheldon Ross's book and I'm a few pages away from learning how to condition on Expected values. So in regards to proceeding from $E[U_1 | U_1 > U_2]$ I hopefully will learn how to do this soon. Again thanks for entertaining how to solve this problem in a more round about way.

Answer (score 1):

"What about the absolute value screws up the linearity of expected values?" This issue has nothing fundamental to do with expected values at all; it's just a property of how numbers behave, and in particular how absolute values do not play nicely with $+$ or $-$. Note, for instance, that $|5 - 7| \neq |5| - |7|$.

"Is there a way to solve this problem using linearity of expectations?" Not an easy one, no. The best you can do is break this up into cases; consider one case where $U_1 > U_2$, and another where $U_2 > U_1$. You will quickly notice that this strongly resembles your direct calculation via double integral.

It's not the linearity of expected values that's burning you here, as they are indeed always linear; it's the (non)-linearity of absolute values.

Comment: Thanks for your insights Aaron, it makes sense.