# How do you calculate $E[U_1 | U_1 > U_2]$ where $U_1$ and $U_2$ are independent Uniform RVs from $(0,1)$

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

**My attempt**

$$E[U_1 | U_1 > U_2] = E[U_1 | U_1 - U_2 > 0] = \int_{0}^{1} u_1 f_{U_1|U_1-U_2}(a|b) du_1$$

The conditional density function is,

$$f_{U_1|U_1-U_2}(a|b) = \frac{f_{U_1,U_1-U_2}(a,b)}{f_{U_1-U_2}(b)}$$

So there are two things that I need to figure out. One is the joint distribution of $U_1$ and $U_1-U_2$ and the second is the marginal distribution of $U_1-U_2$. I know the latter is the triangular distribution from the convolution formula.

Where I'm having trouble is the joint distribution in the numerator.

My strategy is to first calculate the joint cdf and then take the derivative.

$$F_{U_1,U_1-U_2}(a,b) = P(U_1 \le a, U_1 - U_2 \le b) = P(U_1 \le a, - U_2 \le b - a) $$

If there was no negative in front of $U_2$ then I feel I could set up the double integral.

**Motivation**

I actually know the answer is $\frac{2}{3}$ because I know how to calculate $E[|U_1 - U_2|] = \frac{1}{3}$ which is a more straight forward problem to me, and then by using conditioning on $E[|U_1 - U_2|]$ get the answer to $E[U_1|U_1>U_2]$ which you can see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2832741/for-two-standard-uniform-rvs-is-there-a-way-to-find-the-eu-1-u-2-using-the).

However, for this question I'm interested in how to directly calculate $E[U_1|U_1>U_2]$ using the definition of conditional expectation. All the stuff I've learned so far is $E[X|Y=y]$, that is conditional expectation where $Y$ is equal to a specific value, versus something like $X>Y$. Thanks for your help.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2685845/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3991381/321264

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not conditioning over a random variable (or its sigma algebra), but rather over an event.

By definition for conditioning *over a non-zero probability **event***:$$\begin{align}\mathsf E(U_1\mid U_1 > U_2) = &~\dfrac{\mathsf E(U_1\mathbf 1_{U_1>U_2})}{\mathsf P(U_1>U_2)}\\ =&~ \dfrac{\displaystyle \iint_{u>v} u~f_{U_1,U_2}(u,v)~\mathsf d (u, v)}{\displaystyle \iint_{u>v} f_{U_1,U_2}(u,v)~\mathsf d (u, v)}\\ =&~ \dfrac{\displaystyle \int_0^1\int_v^1 u~\mathsf d u~\mathsf d v}{\displaystyle \int_0^1\int_v^1 1~\mathsf d u~\mathsf d v}\\ \vdots~&\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you so much for your guidance. Very interesting... I'm a beginner and so far my book has covered conditioning a RV on another RV... but I see the point you brought up, here this problem is conditioning on an event... I should have suspected something because usually $E[X|Y]$ is itself a RV but my question which conditions on the event $U_1>U_2$ ends up evaluating to a specific number, I believe 2/3. I will need to meditate on this answer... thank you!!