# Expected distance of two points on a rope

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

An 1-meter rope is marked by two points chosen uniformly and independently on the span of the rope. Given that the two points lie on the same half of the rope, what is the expected distance between them?

For example, we choose two points at 0.1 and 0.2 (both <0.5), then the distance is counted as 0.1. If we choose 0.1 and 0.7 (one < 0.5, the other > 0.5), we disregard the result. If we choose 0.8 and 0.8 (both > 0.5), the the distance is 0.

Comment: Under the condition, you are somehow working with truncated uniform which is again a uniform, say on $(0, 0.5)$. Next you can work out the expectation (distribution) of the ordered uniform and subtract them.

Comment: So half the expected distance between two points on the full rope

Comment: Yes, indeed.  Which of course is...

Comment: Convince yourself (e.g. as in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2830236)) that the three intervals formed by two uniformly randomly selected points on an interval all have the same distribution of lengths; then you can deduce the mean length of the central interval (the distance between the two points) by symmetry.